# how can I pass user login credentials after page redirect in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I seem to be having problems saving objects to parse database because after login, the user becomes null. How can I login, and redirect to another page, and then still keep that user as the current user? To be more specific, I want to login browser side, redirect to another page, then call a cloud code function. In that cloud code function I want to ensure that that user is still the current user and then save an object to my database, but like I said after the initial page redirect, current user becomes null. It seems to be not applying useMasterKey because there is no user to modify with the key, so it still is saying unauthorized. I believe solving the null user issue will solve both problems. Code below:

Code to log in:

```
function authenticate() {
    var myname = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var mypass = document.getElementById("psswd").value;

    Parse.User.logIn(myname, mypass, {
        success: function(user) {
            alert("Successfully Logged in!");
            // Do stuff after successful login.
            if(myname == "ebeyj" || myname == "hofmannr" || myname == "xier"){
                window.location.href="itSplash.html";
            }
            else{
                window.location.href="ticketRequest.html";
            }           
        }, 
        error: function(user, error) {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            alert("Failed to login: " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Code to gather info from web browser document to be used to make the ticket object that I am saving:

```
function newRecord() {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if(!currentUser)
        window.location.href="index.html"; //Gets current user info; if non then returns to login
    title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    category = document.getElementById("category").value;
    priority = document.getElementById("priority").value;
    description = document.getElementById("cmnts").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("userlogin").value;
    var dueDate; //set to null. only use this variable if priority is set to high.
    if(priority == "high"){
        dueDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dueDate").value);
    }
    var bcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
    Parse.Cloud.run("createRecord", {title:title, category:category, priority:priority, description:description, username:username, currentUser:currentUser},{
        success: function(result){
            alert("ticket created");
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("error: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

And finally cloud code to create ticket and save it:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createRecord", function(request, response) {
    console.log("starting cloud code");
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var title = request.params.title;
    var category = request.params.category;
    var priority = request.params.priority;
    var description = request.params.description;
    var username = request.params.username;
    var caseClass = Parse.Object.extend("Cases");
    var ticket = new caseClass();
    console.log("started making ticket");
    ticket.set("title", title);
    ticket.set("category", category);
    ticket.set("priority", priority);
    ticket.set("description", description);
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(ticket.save());
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
        console.log(arguments);
    }, function(){
        // this is the error function
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```